# Are there any restrictions for using HTML tags in "html" field?

Tags: google-mirror-api

According to https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline#html
one can use HTML.

Are there any restrictions for using HTML tags in "html" field?

Comment: Gonna need more of an explanation than that, I think.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We will update the documentation regarding this shortly but in the meantime, here are the restrictions:

- **Allowed HTML elements:** Use these elements in your timeline cards.

  - Headers: `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`
  - Images: `img`
  - Lists: `li`, `ol`, `ul`
  - HTML5 semantic: `article`, `aside`, `details`, `figure`,
    `figcaption`, `footer`, `header`, `nav`, `section`, `summary`, `time`
  - Structural: `blockquote`, `br`, `div`, `hr`, `p`, `span`
  - Style: `b`, `big`, `center`, `em`, `i`, `u`, `s`, `small`, `strike`,
    `strong`, `style`, `sub`, `sup`
  - Tables: `table`, `tbody`, `td`, `tfoot`, `th`, `thead`, `tr`
- **Blocked HTML elements:** These elements, and their contents, are removed from
  html payloads.

  - Document headers: `head`, `title`
  - Embeds:  `audio`, `embed`, `object`, `source`, `video`
  - Frames: `frame`, `frameset`
  - Scripting: `applet`, `script`
- **Other elements:** Any elements not listed above are removed, but their
  contents are preserved.

Comment: What about `<iframe>`?

Comment: What attributes of these tags are allowed? e.g. the `onload` attribute of `img`. How are anchor tags handled?