# Allowed HTML tags in timelines

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

While testing the Timeline API I noticed that a number of HTML tags are not accepted by the Mirror API and if so are removed from the created timeline. I did not see a list of accepted tags or denied tags anywhere in the API and the non-authenticated [playground](https://developers.google.com/glass/playground) is misleading as it allows the developer to make false assumptions about what is and is not allowed in the timeline.

So my question is simply: **What tags are allowed and what is unavailable?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045816/are-there-any-restrictions-for-using-html-tags-in-html-field is I think what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post here:

[Are there any restrictions for using HTML tags in "html" field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045816/are-there-any-restrictions-for-using-html-tags-in-html-field)

We'll get it into the documentation very soon.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mirror API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline#html) the following is allowed:

HTML content for this item. If both `text` and `html` are provided for an item, the `html` will be rendered in the timeline.

**Allowed HTML elements** - You can use these elements in your timeline cards.

- Headers: `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`
- Images: `img`
- Lists: `li`, `ol`, `ul`
- HTML5 semantics: `article`, `aside`, `details`, `figure`, `figcaption`, `footer`, `header`, `nav`, `section`, `summary`, `time`
- Structural: `blockquote`, `br`, `div`, `hr`, `p`, `span`
- Style: `b`, `big`, `center`, `em`, `i`, `u`, `s`, `small`, `strike`, `strong`, `style`, `sub`, `sup`
- Tables: `table`, `tbody`, `td`, `tfoot`, `th`, `thead`, `tr`

**Blocked HTML elements:** These elements and their contents are removed from HTML payloads.

- Document eaders: `head`, `title`
- Embeds: `audio`, `embed`, `object`, `source`, `video`
- Frames: `frame`, `frameset`
- Scripting: `applet`, `script`

**Other elements:** Any elements that aren't listed are removed, but their contents are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

[Embedding File using Google Doc](http://techtrace.net/how-to-embed-google-doc-files-in-web-page/) is another cool use of google doc and we can even use it anywhere we can.