# Playing video in the mirror API

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I'm a little confused about playing videos in the Mirror API

[Are there any restrictions for using HTML tags in "html" field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045816/are-there-any-restrictions-for-using-html-tags-in-html-f)...

Alain says

**Blocked HTML elements**: These elements, and their contents, are removed from html payloads.
**Document headers**: head, title
**Embeds**: audio, embed, object, source, video

However looking at the documentation ...

https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/insert

**Accepted Media MIME types**: image/* , audio/* , video/*

So ... I'm guessing that I can attach video but not embed video? Seems like a subtle distinction, so an app would have to have a main HTML card and a sub menu choice to view a video. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

Correct. HTML `video` elements are stripped from inserted timeline cards, but you can attach video. Video that is attached to timeline cards is played in full screen by a native player on Glass.

If you'd like to include video with other rich content, [bundling](https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline#bundling_cards) is the way to go. You can accomplish this by specifying an HTML cover card and many video cards with the same `timelineItem.bundleId`.

Comment: Are you able to overlay simple information on top of video? such as simple text, or small icon?

Comment: Try setting the text or title attributes on the timeline item. Also, for better findability, this may warrant a new question :)